# Closed formula for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, approximation, closed-form, computational-complexity

Let $a_n = x + x^{\frac{1}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{4}} + \dots + x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\gt0$. Find a closed formula for $a_n$ in terms of $x$ or at least an approximation. I need this approximation for computational complexity. Actually, big theta $\Theta$ is what I'm looking for. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

**My try:** Obviously $a_n$ diverges for all $x\not = 0$. Also the geometric series isn't useful here. If we define sequence recursively by $a_{n+1} = a_n + x^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}$ and $a_0 = x$, it can't be solved still using techniques for recursive sequences and I'm stuck here.

Comment: How good an approximation do you want? WIll $a_n \simeq n$ do?

Comment: @RobArthan Please see the edit.

Comment: Are you interested in $n + \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{\sqrt{n}} + \dots + $ till it becomes $1$? Say some algorithm with recurrence $T(n) = O(1) + T(\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, that's the question.

Comment: Do you mean $\Theta(n)$ or $\Theta(x)$ ?? Be explicit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean $\Theta(x)$.

Comment: $a_n$ is $\Theta(x)$ for any $n$, this is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ close to $1$, $x^{1/2^n}\approx 1+\dfrac{x-1}{2^n}$ and the sum of the $n$ first terms is about $n+x-1$.

For large $x$, after sufficiently many square roots, the value comes close to $1$.

An approximation is for instance

$$x+\sqrt[2]x+\sqrt[4]x+\sqrt[8]x+\sqrt[16]x+n-4+\sqrt[16]x-1.$$

Comment: Thanks, please see the edit.